# No such message id pylint

Tags: python, pylint

When I try to pylint a file by doing `pylint fname.py`, I get the following error:
`pylint.utils.UnknownMessage: No such message id E1608`.  However, 'E1608' is certainly a valid message id; it says so on their [website](https://docs.pylint.org/features.html).  What are some possible solutions?

The relevant section of my config file is:

`[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=E1608`

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need

```
disable=old-octal-literal
```

The `disable` flag takes a message, not a message ID, according to the docs. See [here](https://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#what-is-the-format-of-the-configuration-file) for the relevant documentation.

Alternatively, you can put `# pylint: disable=old-octal-literal` at the top of the file in question if the config file is still giving you problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable a message ID instead of a messages, you can do

`disable-msg=E1608`